# #error you must define the platform macro

Tags: c++, macros, cross-platform, c-preprocessor

I have a project that I compile and it gives me following errors as:

```
In file included from c:/acrobatxsdk/Adobe/Acrobat 10 SDK/Version 1/PluginSupport/Headers/API/PIMain.c:21:0:
c:/acrobatxsdk/Adobe/Acrobat 10 SDK/Version 1/PluginSupport/Headers/API/Environ.h:37:2: error: #error You must define the PLATFORM macro
c:/acrobatxsdk/Adobe/Acrobat 10 SDK/Version 1/PluginSupport/Headers/API/Environ.h:41:10: error: #include expects "FILENAME" or <FILENAME>
c:/acrobatxsdk/Adobe/Acrobat 10 SDK/Version 1/PluginSupport/Headers/API/Environ.h:52:2: error: #error PLATFORM failed to #define ACCB1
```

The PIMain.c looks like this :

```
#if WIN_PLATFORM
#include "WinCalls.h"
#elif MAC_PLATFORM
#include "MacCalls.h"
#elif UNIX_PLATFORM
#include "UnixCalls.h"
#else
#error platform not defined
#endif
```

I have come to know that the only amendment if required is to be made in Environ.h , can some one suggest how?

Comment: Which part you dont understand? If it is not your project....You have to create macro. Also paste reall code not errors. We cant do nothing with it.

Comment: well i am including PIMain.c from the ../adobe/API along with PIMain.h and hence worth gt the errors

Comment: What platform are you running on? The code is expecting `WIN_ENV`, `__OS2__`, `unix` or `__unix` to be defined. See http://www.koders.com/c/fid50E5E87FDFFBE3154429B97A5933FAC2498900C4.aspx?s=rsa

Comment: When you say that you "am including PIMain.c", do you mean that you build with it, or that you actually use the `#include` directive to include it? If it's the last, then don't! Source files are not to be included, they are to be compiled and linked with.

Comment: netbeans 7.1 with Mingw 4.6.1 and MSYS

Comment: @Hbcdevi am running on Win7 Home Premium 64 bit

Comment: @JoachimPileborgi am building with it

Answer (score 0):

`Environ.h` is looking for the `PLATFORM` directive and there is a preprocessor or compile time flag to "throw" an error if you do not define it. See how the `#error` directive works here [(MSDN link)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8tk0xsk%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

I found the code for `Environ.h`:

```
#ifndef PLATFORM
#ifdef WIN_ENV
#define PLATFORM "winpltfm.h"
#elif __OS2__
#define PLATFORM "os2pltfm.h"
#elif defined(unix) || defined(__unix)
 #define PLATFORM "UnixPlatform.h"
#else
#error You must define the PLATFORM macro
#endif
#endif
```

You apparently are not running on a supported platform.

Comment: so what changes should i make in here

Comment: @LindaHarrison: I think you need to set WIN_ENV, if it is not set by your compiler explicitly.

Comment: i have set this in the preprocessor definitions as WIN_ENV

Comment: You just have to do this : `#define WIN_ENV`.. as long as its defined, it does not have to be set to anything.